# when cellforrow method of tableview will call

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

I have a `tableView` and it's already loaded.

When I am changing view I add that `tableView` in that view and make it hidden.

But I am not getting why `cellForRowAt(:)` call for that table?

Answer (score 0):

When you are updating or scrolling your tableview cellForRow will get fired. There is no chance for scrolling here because you already hide the tableview.

Comment: Thanks Rick. Is cellForRow will fire when we make it hidden NO or change frame of table?